# Blackjack: do casinos have to use full decks?

Tags: blackjack

In blackjack, with the assumption of a six-deck shoe, does the casino have to use six true decks of cards (i.e all the cards have equal probability at the start, there are only (52x6)! possible shuffles) or can they just use 52x6 cards drawn randomly from a much larger pool (whereby they are picking an assortment with the same number of cards as six decks, but for example can have 10 Ace of clubs cards instead of 6)

Comment: Casinos where? Countries are very different.

Comment: The phrase "only (52x6)!" is hilarious due to the word "only".

Comment: If I understand the game correctly (I might not), while the suits don't matter, the values do. If you just randomly select 52x6=312 cards from a larger batch, you are not going to necessarily get the right mix of values. So if I am a customer and I see the dealer deal out 25 Aces in a row, I am going to get mighty suspicious...

Comment: I think this is primarily a legal question, and almost certainly dependent on jurisdiction. I think you would get better answers on Law.SE (though you would also need more information i.e. where this casino is located). It's possible that there's some kind of international organization that defines "standard" Blackjack, but whether casinos are forced to follow that standard depends on law (and enforcement).

Comment: "have to use" as in do they have a legal obligation? If that's the meaning it probably more suited to Law SE, otherwise it needs to be clarified what the question means. Moral/ethical obligation? Equipment availability? What do you mean?

Comment: If they use a continuous shuffling machine the number cards may be pretty irrelevant.

Comment: I don't think there is a legal question here, I would expect this is just house rules of the casino. So you can ask a particular casino and they should explain to you the rules of the game they offer. This may include an exact list of the cards used for blackjack but it may also just say the casino uses whatever cards they feel like. Your choice to play with these rules or not.

Comment: From the math side of things, the value of the first card drawn as compared to the value of the second card drawn, these will be **dependent** events in the case of a 1-deck shoe or a 6-deck shoe or any other finite number of cards in the card pool.  The more decks used in the shoe, the closer to independent events these become, however with an infinite-shoe they will truly be independent events.  Does it matter in the end?  Not much, but yes it does.  Just because the same list of outcomes are possible does not make the outcomes equally likely in each scenario.

Comment: As per manassehkatz's comment, you can see the dependence of these events by noting that with a six-deck shoe if we had seen 24 aces pulled in a row we should be able to reasonably conclude that the 25'th card can not possibly be an ace.  With an infinite shoe, after seeing 24 aces in a row, the chance the next card is an ace again will still be 1/13 just as always.